# Magma - Coercing a Function Field element to a Rational Function

Tags: elliptic-curves, function-fields, magma-cas

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

I have an elliptic curve $E : y^2 = x^3+x$ over the field $F= GF(43)$. I want to be able to go back and forth between $F(E)$ and $F(x,y)$ in MAGMA.

This is because I have rational functions, $p(x,y)/q(x,y)$, but I want to be able to write the high powers of $y$ as linear functions in $y$ with coefficients in $x$ using the equation for $E$. So, I coerce an expression into the function field of $E$. I have a very messy and ad hoc way of doing it but I'd like to know the "proper way". Here's an example

```
> F:=GF(43);
> R<X>:=PolynomialRing(F);
> E:=EllipticCurve([F!1,F!0]);
> E1,p:=IsogenyFromKernel(E,X);
> S<z,w>:= Parent(IsogenyMapOmega(p));
> omega:=IsogenyMapOmega(p);
> phi:=Evaluate(IsogenyMapPhi(p),z);
> psi := Evaluate(IsogenyMapPsi(p),z);
> SS<a,b>:=FieldOfFractions(S);
> KE<x,y>:=FunctionField(E);
> omega^2/psi;
(a^4*b^2 + 41*a^2*b^2 + b^2)/a
```

I want to take the $b^2$ and substitute $a^3+a$. So I try

`> KE!omega^2/psi`

but MAGMA says its an illegal coercion.

I also want to be able to do substitutions on these expressions, so I need to coerce back to $F(x,y)$, but MAGMA says such a coercion is illegal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define a homomorphism $\varphi: F(u,v) \to F(E)$.

```
k := GF(43);
F<u,v> := RationalFunctionField(k,2);
E := EllipticCurve([k | 1,0]);
kE<x,y> := FunctionField(E);
phi := hom< F -> kE | [x,y] >;
f := (u^4*v^2 + 41*u^2*v^2 + v^2)/u;
phi(f);
```

This returns `x^6 + 42*x^4 + 42*x^2 + 1`.

You can define a lifting map in the other direction that will be a right inverse, but, as you point out in the comments, will not be a homomorphism:

```
g := phi(f);
phi_inv := hom< kE -> F | [u,v]>; 
phi_inv(g);
```

This returns `u^2 + 40*u*v^2 + v^4 + 1`.

Here's a hacky way to get the rational function back represented in the same way as it was in the function field of $E$.

```
cs, mons := CoefficientsAndMonomials(g); 
&+[Evaluate(cs[i],u)*phi_inv(mons[i]) : i in [1..#cs]];
```

With $f = v^{43}$ and $g = \varphi(f)$ as in your example, this returns

```
u^63*v + 21*u^61*v + 38*u^59*v + 40*u^57*v + 8*u^55*v + 10*u^53*v + 41*u^51*v + 8*u^49*v + 14*u^47*v + 25*u^45*v + 30*u^43*v + 30*u^41*v + 25*u^39*v + 14*u^37*v + 8*u^35*v + 41*u^33*v + 10*u^31*v + 8*u^29*v + 40*u^27*v + 38*u^25*v + 21*u^23*v + u^21*v
```

Comment: and what about coercing back to $F(u,v)$? The reverse map isn't a homomorphism.

Comment: I've edited to answer your question.

Comment: I have still have the following problem: If I take say $v^{43}$, then sending it through $phi$ gives a linear polynomial in $y$ with coefficients in $k[x]$ as I want. However, taking that result into phi_inv returns $v^{43}$ again, thus defeating the point of using the function field.

Comment: I see, even though $g$ is printed as `(x^63 + 21*x^61 + 38*x^59 + 40*x^57 + 8*x^55 + 10*x^53 + 41*x^51 + 8*x^49 + 14*x^47 + 25*x^45 + 30*x^43 + 30*x^41 + 25*x^39 + 14*x^37 + 8*x^35 + 41*x^33 + 10*x^31 + 8*x^29 + 40*x^27 + 38*x^25 + 21*x^23 + x^21)*y`, if I ask for `Numerator(g);`, Magma still gives `y^43`, so it's still thinking of it as $y^{43}$ despite printing it a different way. Anyway, I've added an inelegant solution that seems to work.